# I need to upload a .cert file and extract its public key, I'm using the Forge.js framework

Tags: certificate

hello I need to upload a .cert file and extract its public key, I'm using the framework Forge.js from my web application I load the file but I need to extract its public key, how do I do this?[image]

Comment: dont know about the framework. but I use openssl command in linux.

Comment: ok, as would be done with openssl from javascript